# Бизнес-логика для работы с SOAP-запросами на Python

Tags: python, xml, soap

Мне нужно отправлять запросы SOAP-сервису и получать ответы.

Запросы выглядят так:

```
vpuStatus = '''
<vpuStatus version="1.0">
    <fromDate value="01.06.2018"/>
    <toDate value="18.06.2018"/>
    <OperId value=""/>
    <CustomResult value=""/>
</vpuStatus>'''
```

А ответы приходят в таком формате:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <NS1:GetBlockResponse xmlns:NS1="SysEtranInt">
         <return xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</return>
         <Text xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?&gt;
&lt;error&gt;
&lt;errorCode value="4"/&gt;
&lt;errorMessage value="Накладная с ID=1 не найдена или у Вас нет прав доступа к данному документу."/&gt;
&lt;errorStatusCode value="404"/&gt;
&lt;/error&gt;</Text>
      </NS1:GetBlockResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Чем удобнее всего организовать общение с сервисом на питоне? Желательно написать высокоуровневую бизнес-логику, которая будет формировать нужный xml с требуемыми данными, делать запрос и возвращать высокоуровневое (удобное) представление ответа.

Сейчас мы решили использовать zeep для общения с сервисом и xmltodict для конвертирования xml в dict. XML-запросы до сих пор формирую руками. Каким инструментов можно их формировать? Какие структуры данных использовать для работы с ответами?

Comment: Есть несколько библиотек для работы через протокол soap. Конкретную какую-то посоветовать не могу.